# Adding array element in Appsettings.Json, on Azure Devops Release Pipeline Via magic chunks Config transformation

Tags: azure, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, magic-chunks

I am using magic chunks Config transformation on azure devops release pipeline, I am trying to add array element in appsettings.jason, but I could not find any real example how to to it, I created array with following code ->

```
 "my_array[]`0',
```

but it gave result like this :

```
{
      "my_array" : 
     [
       "value" : 1,
     ]
 }
```

it could not add object element in it, I want to create following json in appsetting :

```
{
      "my_array" : 
     [
       {"value" : 1},
       {"value" : 5}
     ]
 }
```

I found that the following code must work but it does not :

```
   my_array[]`0/@value
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have installed this 3rd-party extension: [Magic Chunks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sergeyzwezdin.magic-chunks) in organization. After testing in my side , I get below findings.
Below is appsetting.json.

```
{
      "my_array" : 
     [
       {"value" : 1},
       {"value" : 5}
     ]
}
```

I can then replace its element with following transformations.

```
{
      "my_array[1]/value" : 3
}
```

[image]
And then the result is below.

```
{
  "my_array": [
    {
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "value": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, it always fail if I try to add an element using following transformations.

```
{
      "my_array[2]/value" : 5
}
```

or

```
{
      "my_array[0]/value" : 1,
      "my_array[1]/value" : 3,
      "my_array[2]/value" : 5
}
```

And so on. It seems adding new element is not supported. In the meanwhile, I see you have submitted this feedback here: https://github.com/magic-chunks/magic-chunks-dotnetcore/issues/131, I will monitor it and wish for the author's feedback.

Comment: thank you for response:) I am also looking for authors feedback too

Comment: Hi lekiniu, You could try to replace the element by reference to my transformations and let me know if it works for you too. Looking forward for your reply.

Comment: Does my replace transformations work for you too? Please try it and kindly let me know the result.

Comment: unfortunately, it works differently even when I want to replace, it puts variables in appsettings.json :   "my_array[0]": {
        "value": "3"
    }

Comment: Is your appsettings.json exactly the same with me```{
      "my_array" : 
     [
       {"value" : 1},
       {"value" : 5}
     ]
}``` 
If yes, you can then use replace transformations ```{
      "my_array[0]/value" : 3
 }``` to get the same result as mine.